# Buffer won't print to string

Tags: node.js

Doing this:

```
console.log('val is',val);
console.log('val length is',val.length);
console.log('val toString 2 is',val.toString('2'));
```

Prints this:

```
val is <Buffer 0f 00 f2 03 ac 01 00 00>
val length is 8
```

The third line doesn't print, for some reason. Why might this happen and how can I fix it?

Edit: stupid question on my part. I usually run my buffers through a function that encodes things to string, and forgot to do that for this one.

Comment: [The first argument to `Buffer.toString` is an encoding](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end); I don't think `2` is a valid encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) you need to pass a proper encoding to `toString` as its first argument. Like `ascii` or `utf8`.