# How to read first 1 MB of from 14 GB file in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I want to read first 1 MB from 14 GB of video file.

What I have tried so far?

```
fs.open('/tmp/foo.txt', 'r', function(status, fd) {

if (status) {
  // debug(status.message)
  return
}

var buffer = new Buffer(1024 * 1024);

fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, 1024 * 1024, 0, function(err, num, buffer) {
    console.log(num, buffer)
})
```

I want to some portion of file so that I can extract metadata.

Comment: Does that code not work? If so, does it give an error? If so, post that error.

Comment: Also, in what format are you trying to "read" it? Is it represented in hexadecimal? ascii? utf16le? You'll need to convert your buffer to one of these formats before reading it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190390/buffer-wont-print-to-string

Comment: I want buffer so i can pass to get meta data out out it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a read stream with a start and end.

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream('file', {
    encoding: null,
    start: 0,
    end: 1024 * 1024
});
```

Comment: Can I get buffer from it so I can pass to get metadata from it.

Comment: The stream will emit `data` events with chunks of data as the file is read.  You should extract the metadata in a streaming fashion.